# SSH connection gives no prompt, unresponsive

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, mac-osx-server

I'm ssh'ing from my OSX laptop to an OSX server. It worked a couple of days ago. Now, when I try and connect, no text is output. My session (with -v option) looks like:

```
 ~ $ ssh myserver
```

...

```
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
_
```

Where _ is the cursor.

So it looks to me like I've connected, but something is wrong with the shell - it hasn't started up, or something. Could I have broken my .bash_profile? Are there other common causes of this behaviour?

I don't have root access on this box, and I'd like to be able to give the sysadmins specific things to check for if possible.

EDIT: It's actually an OSX server, not RHEL. (Confusion as it hosts a RHEL VM which I also often connect to.)

I have been sent some server logs:

```
...
Jan 19 11:30:09 myserver sshd[2545]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 error
Jan 19 11:30:09 myserver sshd[2545]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Jan 19 11:30:09 myserver sshd[2541]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for stevebennett from xx.xx.xx.xx port 65411 ssh2
Jan 19 11:30:09 myserver com.apple.SecurityServer[39]: Session 0x2114691 created
Jan 19 11:30:09 myserver com.apple.SecurityServer[39]: Session 0x2114691 attributes 0x20
```

Is the Kerberos 5 error relevant?

Comment: Do you have OS X "parental controls" enabled on this account? I saw this problem once before on OS X (this week actually) and In our case it turned out to be parental controls on the OS X box (the particular SSH server we were connecting to runs on port 80, which may have been a factor.  Don't ask :).

Comment: pretty unlikely I think, but I'll check :)

Comment: ok, looking like the problem is an LDAP connection failure.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something screwed in your profile. Have the admins rename your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and anything else that might be related. If that allows you to log in check the content of each of those files.

Comment: I've managed to rule this out in this case: I'm able to get access to my home directory by other means, and there's nothing odd in either (just a couple of env vars set). Also, it turns out no one else can login either.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was able to resolve this by using DHCP and letting the router assign an IP instead of using a static IP on the server.